# SQLBindParameter for output varchar

Tags: c++, sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that has a `varchar` output parameter:

```
@UserIDOut varchar(50) OUTPUT
```

And in my C++ code I attempt to bind an output parameter to this:

```
...
SQLCHAR userIDOut[50];
int dbReturn = ExecProc(...(SQLCHAR**)&userIDOut);
...

int ExecProc(...SQLCHAR **userIDOut)
{
...
    SQLINTEGER cbParam7 = SQL_NTS;
    retcode = SQLBindParameter(hstmt1, 7, SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_VARCHAR, 50, 0, *userIDOut, 50, &cbParam7);

    retcode = SQLExecDirect(hstmt1, (UCHAR*)"{? = call UpdateUser(?,?,?,?,?,?)}", SQL_NTS);
```

I have several other input parameters, and a return value from this stored procedure.  I've tried a few variations with this function call, and yet I never get anything in `userIDOut`.  If I execute the stored procedure from SQL Server I get the proper output.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You seem to have troubles with pointers in general, unrelated to SQL. A pointer to an array of `SQLCHAR` and a pointer to a pointer to `SQLCHAR` are two very different types.

Comment: @hvd I am aware of such, but I wanted to avoid dynamic allocation in this case.  The documentation on what I need to pass in to receive a `varchar` as output is completely nonexistant.  I don't know if I need a `SQLCHAR*` a `SQLCHAR**` a `SQLCHAR[]*` or what

Comment: [Microsoft's documentation for `SQLBindParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms710963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) contains an example with a string type. Based on that example, you'd need `ExecProc(..., userIDOut)`, `int ExecProc(..., SQLCHAR *userIDOut)`, `SQLBindParameter(..., userIDOut, 50, &cbParam7);`. `userIDOut` would already be a pointer to the buffer, so you don't need to dereference it inside `ExecProc`.

Comment: @hvd I see no examples in there they use a `SQLCHAR*` as a `SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT`

Comment: Right, but that should not make any difference, should it? Input or output, in both cases you pass a pointer to the buffer the same way, the only difference is who writes to the buffer and who reads from it.

Comment: Well, that seems to have been the problem, go ahead and post it as the answer and the bounty is yours.  I can't believe the types won't even work like that

Comment: I've included a little bit more detail in my answer, if you have any question about it feel free to ask and I'll try to elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments:

You need to pass a pointer to `userIDOut` to `SQLBindParameter`. What you are passing isn't a pointer to `userIDOut`, but rather, the first bytes of `userIDOut` reinterpreted as a pointer.

An array is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element (and since an array is stored contiguously in memory, this makes the rest of the data accessible too), so you don't need to write `&userIDOut`, you can just write `userIDOut` if you change the type to `SQLCHAR *`.

```
int ExecProc(..., SQLCHAR *userIDOut)
{
  ...
  ... SQLBindParameter(..., userIDOut, 50, &cbParam7);
  ...
}

// To call
... ExecProc(..., userIDOut);
```

You could, if you wish, continue to work with a pointer to `userIDOut`, but that requires you to use a pointer to an array, not a pointer to a pointer, and pointers to arrays use an awkward syntax and don't generally have any more value than pointers to one of the array's elements:

```
int ExecProc(..., SQLCHAR (*userIDOut)[50])
{
  ...
  ... SQLBindParameter(..., userIDOut, 50, &cbParam7);
  ...
}

// To call
... ExecProc(..., &userIDOut);
```

Comment: I understand why it wasn't working now, due to the fact that in this context `userIDOut` is the same as `&userIDOut`.  What I cannot understand for the life of me is WHY `&userIDOut` DOES NOT point to the actual variable's location on the stack

Comment: @DanF It does, but inside `ExecProc`, you weren't passing `userIDOut` (which was a pointer to the buffer), but `*userIDOut` (the first bytes of the buffer).

Comment: `&userIDOut` points to the first element of the array, just as `userIDOut` does.  I have searched a bit and have yet to find a valid explanation for that incredibly confusing behavior

Comment: @DanF Right, with very few exceptions (taking the address is such an exception), `userIDOut`, when `userIDOut` is an array, is equivalent to `&userIDOut[0]`. And `&userIDOut[0]` and `&userIDOut` point to the same location in memory. I'm not sure to what extent this helps you, but the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html) has an entry about it. I know you've tagged your question C++, but this is something that works the same in both languages.

Comment: I guess my question is if `userIDOut` were any other (non-array) type, then `userIDOut != &userIDOut`.  I do not understand the rationale for why the exception was made for arrays that `&variable == variable`;

Comment: @DanF `&array[0]` and `&array` point to the same location, but have different types. `array == &array[0]`, but `array == &array` would give a compiler error for a type mismatch. The reason for that conversion is partly historical, but it's indirectly because arrays aren't actually supported by processors directly. The built-in operator `[]` is defined for pointers, not for arrays, and the way arrays get converted to pointers makes `[]` do the right thing.